# In latest version of React-native(0.61.1) Google maps shows blank screen in android and ios

Tags: google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

I am using react-native-maps to display the map in react-native, and i getting the blank screen in ios and android. It just shows google logo but the map does not display anything. in IOS default ios map works fine.

I am using
`react-native: 0.61.1`,
`react-native-maps: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps.git,`
and I tried the latest react-native-maps version also `react-native-maps: 0.26.1`, but not able to display google maps in react-native.

my pods:

```
`pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'react-native-maps', path: '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: '../node_modules/react-native-maps'`
```

my dependencies:

**build.gradle**

```
`ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "15.0.1"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
    }`
```

**app level build.gradle**

```
`implementation project(':react-native-maps')
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.0'
 implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"`
```

I followed the https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md to integrate react-native-maps.

**Here is the default ios map**
[image: default ios map]

**Here is the google map in ios**
[image: google map in ios]